# VC++ file equivalents in Dot_Net/C#

Tags: .net, visual-c++, ncb

This is first time, I am trying to migrate one application from VC++ to Dot Net. During my analysis I found NCB, CLW, DSP, DSW, vcxproj and vcxproj.filter files in VC++ but I don't have any clue about their equivalents in Dot_Net/C#.
(Note : before asking this question, I checked for duplicate but could not find)

Do we need to create files with above extensions in Dot_Net/C# or they will be automatically created?
Can somebody please guide me?

Comment: It was the IntelliSense database for C++ projects in ancient versions of VS.  No equivalent since none is needed, you can simply delete it.

Comment: thank you. However, I have updated this question (just to avoid unnecessary other questions). If you don't mind, can you please re-look and again guide?

Comment: None of those are relevant, focus only on the source code.